# if ajax.responseText contains

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, responsetext

i'd like to check for a presence of a particular word in the response text and perform some conditions there after, how do i do that. so far i can only get a "true" from php

```
 function checkCellNo() {

      var cnv = _("CellNo").value;

      if (cnv != "") {

          $("#CellNostatus")
              .html('Checking your number: ...')
              .css('background-image', 'url(images/IMG_8482.GIF)')
              .append($('#CellNo').val());

          var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "ucheck.php");

          ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {

              if (ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                  _("CellNostatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
              }

              ajax.send("CellNocheck=" + cnv);
          }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `indexOf`

```
if (!(ajax.responseText.indexOf('yourword') == -1)) {
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Not working, always returns everything like it contains the word.